# Silverlight ScrollViewer not updating after zoom

Tags: zooming, scrollviewer

I have a Silverlight grid with a bunch of content in it (rectangles, textBlocks, etc.) which represents content in a room. Because it gets pretty complex, I decided I needed an ability to "zoom-in" on the grid.  I found some good code to do that, but the problem is that after zooming the grids associated ScrollViewer doesn't scroll the full distance down or to the right. How can I force it to update so that I can scroll to the bottom and all the way to the right?

If it helps, here's the code to permit zooming of my Grid:

```
var style = new Style(typeof(Grid));
var scale = new ScaleTransform();
scale.CenterX = .5;
scale.CenterY =.5;
scale.ScaleX = Scale;
scale.ScaleY = Scale;
var rs = new Setter();
rs.Property = DataGridCell.RenderTransformProperty;
rs.Value = scale;
style.Setters.Add(rs);
OtdrPatchLocationGrid.Style = style;
```

and here is the XAML that shows the grid and the scroll viewer

```
    <ScrollViewer Name="scViewer"  Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Visible"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <Grid x:Name="OtdrPatchLocationGrid" MinHeight="350"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Background="Yellow" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0" MouseDown="OtdrRackViewer_MouseDown">

        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the same issue now,

the ScrollViewer is affected only by the change in Width or Height,
so to fix the problem, you have to do as the following:

suppose we got the Grid or Canvas named (ZoomCanvas)

in the code behind:

```
double initialCanvasHeight;
double initialCanvasWidth;
public void MainPage() //As the Constructor
{
 initialCanvasHeight = ZoomCanvas.Height;
 initialCanvasWidth = ZoomCanvas.Width;
}

ZoomCanvas_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{

/*Assuming you have the scaling code here and the object CanvasScale is used to scale the canvas*/

 foreach (var node in ZoomCanvas)
            {
                var nodeTop = Canvas.GetTop(node);
                var nodeLeft = Canvas.GetLeft(node);
                if(mostTopValue < nodeTop)
                    mostTopValue = nodeTop;
                if(mostLeftValue < nodeLeft)
                    mostLeftValue = nodeLeft;
                var desiredHeight = (mostTopValue + NodeHeight)*canvasScale.ScaleY;
                var desiredWidth = (mostLeftValue + NodeWidth) * canvasScale.ScaleX;
                if (desiredHeight > canvasInitialHeight)
                {
                    while (heightToIncrease < desiredHeight)
                        heightToIncrease += 10;
                    ZoomCanvas.Height = heightToIncrease;
                }
                else
                    while (ZoomCanvas.Height > canvasInitialHeight)
                        ZoomCanvas.Height -= 10;
                if (desiredWidth > canvasInitialWidth)
                {
                    while (widthToIncrease < desiredWidth)
                        widthToIncrease += 10;
                    ZoomCanvas.Width = widthToIncrease;
                }
                else while (ZoomCanvas.Height > canvasInitialHeight)
                    ZoomCanvas.Width -= 10;
            }
            scrollViewer.UpdateLayout();
}
```